# How to generate all decreasing sequences generated from a list?

Tags: algorithm

Given a list `a = [a0, a1, a2, ...]` (not necessarily without duplicates), I'd like to generate all decreasing sequences `b = [b0, b1, b2...]` such that each element `bi` is a product of elements in `a`, but no element in `a` is in more than one element in `b`.

**Edit:** All elements in `a` must be used.

For example, for `[2, 3, 4]`, the possible sequences are:

- `[4, 3, 2]`
- `[12, 2]`
- `[24]`
- `[6, 4]`
- `[8, 3]`

Is there an efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: Is it ur homework?  its same as string permutation, try that.

Comment: This is not homework, though I'm complimented that you think it is - I figure that means I wrote the problem very clearly. I could go through each permutation, and then for each permutation go through each product and sort, but I'm looking for a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Ignoring the duplicates for a moment, this seems equivalent to finding all partitions of the set a. Btw., you did not specify if all the elements in a must be used. From the examples it seems so.